# HTMLU form submit giving 200 instead of 302 after first time

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, htmlunit

I was able to login to a website the first time but for later requests with different credentials, HTMLUnit is giving 200 instead of 302.

Any ideas why I'm not getting 302 for successive requests? I believe it's because the server is sending:

```
Expires: Sun, 12 Jul 2015 01:24:57 GMT[\r][\n]"
2015-07-11 11:25:01,968 DEBUG [org.apache.http.wire:63][pool-6-thread-2] - << "Cache-Control: public, max-age=36000[\r][\n]"
```

in response. How do I overcome this?

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(Url);
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("form_name");
final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue("Sign In");
final HtmlTextInput user = form.getInputByName("username");

user.setValueAttribute("admin");

final HtmlPasswordInput pass = form.getInputByName("password");
pass.setValueAttribute("admin");

final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
HtmlAnchor anchor = page2.getAnchorByText("logout");
anchor.click();
webClient.getCache().clear();
webClient.getCookieManager().clearCookies();
webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

I'm using this code from Liferay Tomcat.

Comment: HTTP 302 -> Found.  It's tough for us to say why your code is generating that if we *can't see your code*...

Comment: Did you configure the `WebClient` to use a `CookieManager`?

Comment: @Makoto, included code I'm using

Comment: @hzpz, I've not explicitly configured any cookiemanager, its the default I'm using, included my code in the question

Comment: At which point do you expect the 302 redirect? When requesting `Url` or when clicking the link?

Comment: @hzpz,when clicking the link (button.click())

Comment: Do you create a new `WebClient` for each request? Or are you reusing it?

Comment: @hzpz,I'm creating a new webclient for each request, the first time I got 302 redirect but when I try with different users from second time onwards I get 200 because server is sending a cookie that expires after 10 hours (maxage=36000)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83148/discussion-between-hzpz-and-user3487063).

Comment: You need provide all details (URL) to compare the behavior against real browsers.